# How do I create multiple TCP clients connections using multi-threading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I have an issue with the code below. The purpose of the function is to create multiple TCP clients (I introduce the number I want in a text box in winform) and to connect them to the server, each one using a different thread.
I also want to assign to each one of the clients a different port. I tried to use random functions to generate random numbers and assign each one as a client's port, but somehow random functions block the main ui thread, so I figured out that a better approach would be using a variable and incrementing it everytime a client is created and then assign it as a port.
The problem is that none of my approaches work. When I run the app and press the Connect button, it only logs "0 of x clients have connected" (x being the number I introduce in the textbox, representing how many clients I want to connect).
This is my code:

```
 private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string hostname = txtIP.Text;
            int numberOfConnectedClients = 0;
            int port;
            int clientPort = 30000;




            if (!int.TryParse(txtPort.Text, out port))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid port number!");
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostname))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an IP address!");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                int.TryParse(txtNumberOfDevices.Text, out totalNumberOfClients);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error : {ex.Message}. Enter a valid number of clients.");
            }
            if (totalNumberOfClients <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number of clients.");
                return;
            }




            //  clients = new List<TcpClient>();
            //   clients.Add(client);

            

               for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfClients; i++)
               {
                   Thread clientThread = new Thread(() =>
                   {
                       try
                       {


                            client = new TcpClient();

                           client.Connect(hostname, clientPort);

                           WriteLog($"The client {i} has connected to server on port {clientPort}");

                           Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfConnectedClients);



                       }
                       catch (Exception ex)
                       {
                           WriteLog($"Client {i} couldn't connect on port {clientPort}. Error : {ex.Message}");
                       }

                   });

                   clientThread.Start();
                   clientPort++;

                   // Thread.Sleep(100);



               }


               WriteLog($"{numberOfConnectedClients} clients from {totalNumberOfClients} clients have connected!");


          

        }
```

Please give me a solution for successfully connecting the clients on different threads and on different ports.

Comment: A TCP connection has three properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  You cannot make more than one connection with the three properties the same.  So if you want multi-threading you need on the server to open more than one port.  You can't change the source nor destination IP.

Comment: You can use the asynchronous methods of TcpClient and Stream to avoid blocking. You don't need a separate thread per client. `somehow random functions block the main ui thread` no they don't. Calling `Connect` though will block until the connection succeeds. `await client.ConnectAsync()` won't block the UI

Comment: In thread initialization, lock the portion of code where you "connect'()" and increment clientPort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help! check it...
Add what you nedd to your class!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.StartUp();

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Main coordinator
    /// </summary>
    void StartUp()
    {           
        Task T1 = StartSockets();
        Task.WaitAll(T1);
    }`
    ///<summary>
    /// Async void task to connect to different sockets
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task StartSockets()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Socket_Method("192.168.0."+i+"", 8080));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            //LOGGEN.Log(@"-------------------- JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f));
            Thread.Sleep(800);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This sockets connects to a passive TCP/IP server a sends a JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="IP">IP From passive TCP/IP Server</param>
    /// <param name="Port">Connection port from passive TCP/IP server</param>
    void Socket_Method(string IP, Int32 Port)
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            using (socket)
            {
                socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port));
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BoltRadar_Json)));
                    //LOGGEN.Log(@"\-----------JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BoltRadar_Json));
                    socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            socket.Close();
            //LOGGEN.Log(@"--------------JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f).ToString());
            StartUp();
        }

    }
```